# ASP.NET Tag Helper With Html Elements Inside

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

In asp.net core project I have tag helper which allows html content, e.g.:

```
<my-tag><div>some content</div></my-tag>
```

Visual Studio 2017 gives me a warning: element 'div' cannot be nested inside element 'my-tag'.

But my-tag is really a div element. So this markup is OK. Is it possible to disable this warning for custom tag?

Answer (score 0):

1. > In Solution Explorer, choose the project in which you want to suppress warnings.
2. > On the menu bar, choose View > Property Pages. Choose the Build page.
3. > In the Suppress warnings box, specify the error codes of the warnings that you want to suppress, separated by semicolons.

Comment: I don't want to supress this warning. I want some option for it to work correctly with tag helpers.

Comment: After doing some research it looks like it could be a loading order issue perhaps.

Comment: speaking about the helper tags "You can place it right inside your application project, but you need to tell the Razor view engine about the tag helper." . Have you declared it in your razor view?